# Node.js : my server request hot-update.js when I try to launch my application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a weird error since today, for no apparent reasons, i get this message in the back-end terminal whenever I try to launch my back-end and front-end :

**"GET /main.e4d789223cfc4d592f75.hot-update.js 404 3.707 ms - 289"**

It just loops indefinitely and I can't access my app anymore.

Weirdly also, it worked completely fine before, and it appeared without me touching anything in npm, proxys or back-end.

I tried to look up online but there are no useful answers.

**Here My package.json server-side**

```
 {
  "name": "workfromhome",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd reactapp && npm install && npm run build"
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "force-ssl-heroku": "^1.0.2",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.13",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "node-mailjet": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "stripe": "^8.122.1",
    "sync-request": "^6.1.0",
    "uid2": "0.0.3"
  }
}
```

And my package.json front

```
"name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/colors": "^5.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^5.8.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.12",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "antd": "^4.8.2",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "craco-less": "^1.17.0",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-animated-css": "^1.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.13",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-sticky-box": "^0.9.3",
    "react-typical": "^0.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "secure": false,
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the command you're using to start the server and the output?

Comment: i use "nodemon".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its working now. I just restarted Visual Studio. Thank you